# Why does json.load() return a LIST type

Tags: python, json

I am following a book and learning python, and I have the following code:

```
import json

with open("books.json", "rt") as file:
    books = json.load(file)
    
print(books)

print(type(books))
```

the JSON file can be found here:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PacktPublishing/Learning-Python-Networking-Second-Edition/master/Chapter03/json/books.json

According to the book, my code should print type `<class 'dict'>` but is printing `<class 'list'>`

Do you know why this is? Is this the expected behavior in this case? Thanks. I tested having only one dictionary in the file, as opposed to the 2, and still getting the LIST type.

Edit: using python 3.9.4

Comment: The data **is** a list since it's enclosed with `[]`. There are multiple dicts inside this list though.

Comment: `load` returns whatever is decoded from the file. Not every JSON value is an object.

Comment: Even just `[]` is a list -- it doesn't matter how many things are inside it, so going from a list with two things to a list with one thing makes no difference.

Comment: Packt unfortunately isn't known in my circles for having good content. I bought their humble bundle earlier this year and was told to take a lot of what they say with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1):

This happens, because it is a list of dict-elements, try this:

```py
print(type (books[0]))
```

Comment: yep, tried that already and was getting a dict for the specific item, I am presuming either the book doesn't give the correct info, or I have some outdated stuff; thank you all for the confirmation, since it was driving me nuts